# Async await call

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, async-await, xml-rpc

I am having trouble understanding how to use async/await in my case scenario
MY CODE IS IMPLEMENTED AS FOLLOWS

```
getUserInfo = function () {
    async.waterfall([
        getActiveUser, getUsername, update],
        function(err , result){
            console.log(result)
        });


         function getActiveUser(callback) {
         //i have a db search to find who is active right now
             user.find({status: 'active'}, function (err , users){
                callback(err, users)
             })
         }




          function getUsername(users, callback) {
               async.map(users, getUserInfoXmlrpc, function (err, result) {
                  callback(err, result);
               });
          }

          function getUserInfoXmlrpc(user, doneCallback) {
               // i make a xmlrpc call based on dates
          }


}
```

i am having difficulties make the xmlrpc call for more than one day.
I tried to implement async await creating a function that stores the dates i need in an array but i couldn't make it work.
Any ideas what can i do cause i want to update users one by one as i am doing right now but have to check their info updates based on a xmlrpc call

Comment: `async-await` are for `promises` you cannot use that with `callback` model.

Comment: are you trying to await the xmlrpc call inside getUserInfoXmlrpc?

Comment: @davidgamero as xmlrpx call parameters i pass the userid and a specific date. I want to call the dates inside a function the user inside get usename and pass the both as params to xmlrpc call

Comment: @ArditKurti what happens when you call the xmlrpc for multiple dates? Is the request failing? Can you check your network tab to see if all the requests are being made?